# Teams bot, transfer a call to another application / voicemail

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

In our Teams calling bot, we would like to transfer certain calls to specific Teams users, PSTN, but also to an other Teams calling bot and/or voicemail.

For specific Teams users and PSTN we got it working. If we want to transfer a call to another application, we can do so by using its pstn number. But ideally we would also like to transfer using its objectId.

I tried using a transferrequest like this:

```
      var requestBody = new CallTransferRequestBody()
        {
            TransferTarget = new InvitationParticipantInfo()
            {
                Identity = new IdentitySet()
                {
                    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                }
            }
        };
     requestBody.TransferTarget.Identity.Application = new Identity { Id = transferTargetId };
     //this line does not make any difference
     requestBody.TransferTarget.Identity.Application.SetTenantId(tenantId);
```

But this results in a "Request authorization tenant mismatch." error. Is it possible to directly transfer to another application?

I haven't tried voicemail boxes yet, but if any info on how to transfer to those, is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Basically we can transfer an active peer-to-peer call. This is only supported if both the transferee and transfer target are Microsoft Teams users that belong to the same tenant.

However for redirecting call to call queue or auto attendants, you can use the "applicationInstance" identity. The bot is expected to redirect the call before the call times out. The current timeout value is 15 seconds.

```
const requestBody = {
"targets": [{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.invitationParticipantInfo",
    "identity": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identitySet",

        "applicationInstance": {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identity",
            "displayName": "Call Queue",
            "id": queueId
        }
    }
}],}
```

Please refer to the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-redirect?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#request

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, but what is the difference with my implementation? I am using the sdk with requestBody.TransferTarget.Identity.Application, which translates to the json you provide (as far as i can see and apart from displayname). Via an other channel I was told that redirecting to applications is not yet supported.

Comment: Redirecting an incoming call is possible if it hasn't been answered or rejected yet.

Comment: Yes, i was using the wrong term in my comment. I am asking about transfer.

Comment: Transfer from peer to peer call is possible. As per my understanding transferring the call to other application doesn't seems to be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect API is still having that limitation from my understanding.
But that should work with the new Transfer API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-transfer?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My question is about the API you send a link for.